# Node 8.0 install, but npm stuck on old version

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10, updates

Installed node version v8 on windows 10. It says it comes delivered with npm 5....
But it's stuck on 3.5.3

```
λ npm i -g npm
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393

npm ERR! argv "npm" "i" "-g" "npm"

npm ERR! node v8.0.0

**npm ERR! npm  v3.5.3**

**npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND**

**npm ERR! Cannot find module 'internal/fs'**
npm ERR!

npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>


npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\npm-debug.log
```

What  i've done:

- Uninstall node and reinstall it
- Install a different version of node (7.7.0) and see if it updated npm
- used npm clean cache -f

And none of these things worked...
So any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an older version in your path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and had to run

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

from the command line. I was told node and npm versions will be different.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -

sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: Any explanation for how/why this fixes the problem would improve your answer.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem - this will help not just the OP but others with similar issues. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)